# Distributing free software (Qt)

Tags: licensing

I have built a small program for plotting data from serial port using Qt and QCustomPlot. I am an engineering student, and I had a project that required me to manipulate data from the ADC of an mbed, so I built this app for my convenience and for experience. I would like to share it with other people who need such a tool (will put it on the mbed website).

I am not a programmer and I do not know a thing about licenses. The QCustomPlot is under GPL. I read that I cannot use static linkage with the GPL licence for QT; I do not intend to, (I will post the source too), but would like to include a statically built version of the program for people who would rather just use the program.

So without going in too much detail, what can I do? Also, do I need to include any disclaimers in my source?

Comment: You should read something about [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.html). I suggest you to put your source code on e.g. [github](http://github.com/). Don't bother about the binaries (because each system needs its own binary)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: choose a license for your software. The website http://choosealicense.com can help you in doing that. 
Usually a license requires to add a text header to your source code files. This is just a fragment of text which shows the terms of the license right within the source code. 
Also, a license.txt file is often required in which the full license has to be pasted. Anyway choosealicense.com clearly explains what to do. 
Notice that some licenses (e.g. the GPL) need that a list of changes is added to your source code. This list has to be mantained through the entire life of your software distribution and updated when you provide new releases. 
When you are ready with your package use a website like GitHub to distribute it as a source code.
Do not include binaries. Just add the source code and a README file in which you explain how to compile them.